# Rebuild index failed on Hive on Azure HDInsight with Tez

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I try to create indexes on Hive on Azure HDInsight with Tez enabled.
I can successfully create indexes but I can't rebuild them : the job failed with this output :

```
Map 1: -/-  Reducer 2: 0/1  
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1421234198072_0091_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex Input: measures initializer failed.]
Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1421234198072_0091_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex > received Kill in INITED state.]
DAG failed due to vertex failure. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
```

I have created my table and indexes with the following job :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Measures;
CREATE TABLE Measures(
    topology string,
    val double,
    date timestamp,
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://<mycontainer>@<mystorage>.blob.core.windows.net/';

CREATE INDEX measures_index_topology ON TABLE Measures (topology) AS 'COMPACT' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;
CREATE INDEX measures_index_date ON TABLE Measures (date) AS 'COMPACT' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;
ALTER INDEX measures_index_topology ON Measures REBUILD;
ALTER INDEX measures_index_date ON Measures REBUILD;
```

Where am I wrong ? And why my rebuilding index fail ?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Tez might have a problem with generating an index on an empty table.  I was able to get the same error as you (without using the JSON SerDe), and if you look at the application logs for the DAG that fails, you might see something like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.init(HiveInputFormat.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.getSplits(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:68)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.hadoop.MRHelpers.generateOldSplits(MRHelpers.java:263)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.common.MRInputAMSplitGenerator.initialize(MRInputAMSplitGenerator.java:139)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerRunner$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerRunner.java:154)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerRunner$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerRunner.java:146)
    ...
```

If you populate the table with a single dummy record, it seems to work fine.  I used:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE Measures SELECT market,0,0 FROM hivesampletable limit 1;
```

After that, the index rebuild was able to run without error.