# Hive index creation using TEZ

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

Is it possible to generate indexes using Tez instead of MR job? When we try to set the hive.execution.engine=Tez and try to generate index then the index creation is failing.
Below are the list of commands that i have used:

CREATE TABLE table02(column1 String, column2 bigint, column3 string);
CREATE INDEX table02_index ON TABLE table02 (column3) AS 'COMPACT' WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;
ALTER INDEX table02_index ON table02 REBUILD;

Index creation failed with below error message: 
**FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask**

So, for index creation on a table do we always have to set hive.execution.engine=mr even if we want to use TEZ to perform queries on the data in that table? Is it limitation for TEZ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948062/rebuild-index-failed-on-hive-on-azure-hdinsight-with-tez